# Need to use grep and sort for matching records and display Y and N

Tags: text-processing, sort

**Input file** (contain column 1 with repeat value in number and second column may contain voice,email, tel, voice mail):

```
123,voice
123, tel
324,voice mail
345,email
123,email
```

**Output file** with headers and required `Y` if they have any value in column two else `N`

```
number,voice,voice mail,tel,email
123,Y,N,Y,N,Y
324,N,Y,N,N,N
345,N,N,N,N,Y
```

Comment: Why should this be done with `grep`? Does the homework require that?

Comment: No was using it and getting error but not necessary.

Comment: You should adjust the title of your question then.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -F'\s*,\s*' -lane '
    BEGIN{ $outfile = "output_file_name";
           open $OUTFILE , ">" , $outfile
    }
    $h{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++;
    END{
        $i{$_}++ for map {keys $h{$_}} keys %h;
        print $OUTFILE "number,".join ",",sort keys %i;
        for $number (keys %h) {
           $string = "$number,";
           $string .= $h{$number}{$_} ? "Y," : "N," for keys %i;
           $string =~ s/,$//;
           print $OUTFILE $string
        }
    } ' input_file
```

Code tested and works with your example input. Just modify `output_file_name` to be the actual name you want for your output file.

**Warning**

This will clobber the output file if it exists. If you would rather append to it, change `">"` to `">>"` on the 3rd line.

Comment: Getting error in the script, syntax error at -e line 8, near "$number ("
syntax error at -e line 14, near ";}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @user_tmo The code, as posted above, works perfectly for me. Are you sure you are copying it correctly? Note that I had a missing semicolon in an earlier version that I fixed in an edit.

Comment: When the value string length is long (8 to 15 characters) in the column two for input file, it is not adding the full header just last column name is seen in output file.

Comment: @user_tmo Is it possible that some of these value strings contain commas?

Comment: It does not contain comma but have underscore in them like email_pref, directmail_pref